# how to add components to a subclass of a subclass of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, subclass, jcomponent

I have a subclass of JFrame A. I have another class B which is the subclass of A. I want to add new components to frame B like JButtons. My code is as follows:

```
public B() extends A {
    //Calling super class constructor
    super();

    //Creating and adding a button 
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    this.add(btn);

    //other codes
}
```

When I display the frame, the button isn't added, and only the superclass frame and its components are displayed. How can I add those buttons in the subclass B's frame?

Update: Here is a condensed version of my code. I've used BorderLayout in super class **ListObjects**.

```
package assignment2;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListAndModifyCustomer extends ListObjects {

public ListAndModifyCustomer() {
    //Calling super class constructor
    super("Customers");

    //Adding listener to the ok button
    super.selectBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //codes to create another JFrame

            dispose();  //Closing the frame
        }
    });

    //Adding button to the panel
    super.panel.add(new JButton("NO"));

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.add(super.selectBtn);

    super.add(jp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

Comment: We need a little bit more info. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) to illustrate what you are doing? In particular, I wonder what `LayoutManager` you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if we create a panel in the subclass and add all the items to that panel and add that panel to the frame of the super class then the components become visible.

Answer (score 0):

do `this.getContentPane().add(btn)`.
 I cannot comment more as there is no info on what components, layout etc are used.

Comment: no, no need to explicitly add to the contentPane - please read the api doc of frame.add

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is the `BorderLayout`. A `BorderLayout` can only contain one component in each of its locations. If you do not specify a location, the `CENTER` location will be used.

So if both your `ListObjects` class and the `ListAndModifyCustomer` class do a call to `add` without specifying the location, only the seceond component will be visible (and added).

Comment: can u demo specifying the location as i couldn't grasp it @robin

Comment: @nick-s See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for samples